# slsvc service won't start - error code 5

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update, licensing

I've Windows Vista SP2. My problem is that Windows Update does not work.
I found that slsvc (software licensing service) is disabled on my computer.
When I tried to  restart it, I got the error message `Error 5. Access Denied`.

I don't know what to do. Restoring the system is probably impossible.

The sfc /scannow command returned log is available here - tymonradzik.cba.pl/CBS.zip (you **have to enter that manually** to URL Field) - for download.

Some lines from the log:

> 2014-02-11 22:01:56, Info                  CSI    000001e2 Ignoring
>   duplicate ownership for directory
>   [l:54{27}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\WCN" in component
>   Microsoft-Windows-WCN-Config-Registrar-Wizard2.Resources, Version =
>   6.1.6002.18005, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture = [l:10{5}]"pl-PL", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8
>   b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral
>
> 2014-02-11 22:01:56, Info                  CSI    000001e3 Ignoring
>   duplicate ownership for directory
>   [l:66{33}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\WCN\pl-PL" in component
>   Microsoft-Windows-WCN-Config-Registrar-Wizard2.Resources, Version =
>   6.1.6002.18005, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture = [l:10{5}]"pl-PL", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8
>   b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral
>
> 2014-02-11 22:04:23, Info                  CSI    0000022a [SR] Cannot
>   repair member file [l:22{11}]"msxml4r.dll" of Microsoft.MSXML2R,
>   Version = 4.1.0.0, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture
>   neutral, VersionScope neutral, PublicKeyToken = {l:8
>   b:6bd6b9abf345378f}, Type = [l:10{5}]"win32", TypeName neutral,
>   PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
>
> 2014-02-11 22:04:23, Info                  CSI    0000022b Hashes for
>   file member \??\C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll do not match actual file
>   [l:18{9}]"ole32.dll" :   Found: {l:32
>   b:emW2JolAJ513zgjWlTBhUKj43ZpoeNKjInmaxXaWDGs=} Expected: {l:32
>   b:Z0qvZlltTzVkqCGErZgZWuTt0sBbLldcOxvGeUGWU/8=}
>
> 2014-02-11 22:04:23, Info                  CSI    0000022c [SR]
>   Repairing corrupted file
>   [ml:520{260},l:46{23}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32"[l:18{9}]"ole32.dll"
>   from store
>
> 2014-02-11 22:04:23, Info                  CSI    0000022d Hashes for
>   file member \??\C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iecompat.dll do not
>   match actual file [l:24{12}]"iecompat.dll" :   Found: {l:32
>   b:IcHEUbnFfpfr4A9Q3cIkFAFTfv02theGUDHs3hd366Q=} Expected: {l:32
>   b:64fGcWZtwScot47uausAEh5d7y5zmXC7O6eZqg4ATI8=}
>
> 2014-02-11 22:04:23, Info                  CSI    0000022e [SR]
>   Repairing corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:76{38}]"\??\C:\Program
>   Files\Internet Explorer"[l:24{12}]"iecompat.dll" from store
>   2014-02-11 22:04:23, Info                  CSI    0000022f Hashes for
>   file member \??\C:\Windows\System32\mfc40u.dll do not match actual
>   file [l:20{10}]"mfc40u.dll" :   Found: {l:32
>   b:6u+rXz7b2apRm5ggPCjM0dPFGnWr/kQqhrDtIkRSwrQ=} Expected: {l:32
>   b:asi9vidDcg6byG7lKldJtIxl2wA2twI+nA4VUSbRNtI=}
>
> 2014-02-11 22:04:23, Info                  CSI    00000230 [SR]
>   Repairing corrupted file
>   [ml:520{260},l:46{23}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32"[l:20{10}]"mfc40u.dll"
>   from store
>
> 2014-02-11 22:04:23, Info                  CSI    00000231 Hashes for
>   file member
>   \??\C:\Windows\System32\licensing\ppdlic\MovieMaker-ppdlic.xrm-ms do
>   not match actual file [l:48{24}]"MovieMaker-ppdlic.xrm-ms" :   Found:
>   {l:32 b:MqSqZBxih5g3WEOxhw80Lru6V+1nLdYYrJOW9gOlKEQ=} Expected: {l:32
>   b:KZuEJHoOONlh89DMPOW9MA8tHnigy+w8oV+EwmkbKHU=}
>
> 2014-02-11 22:04:23, Info                  CSI    00000232 [SR]
>   Repairing corrupted file

Comment: Basically the `msxml4.dll` and `msxml4r.dll` files are missing. Without the full `CSB.log` file, I wouldn't know whether there are other issues, though.

Comment: @and31415 done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows installation looks to be completely corrupted and
your file-system is also in a bad shape.
The examination of your "sfc /scannow" log shows that not only you have corrupted Windows DLLs, but you also have permission errors on system files, and even your Windows activation is probably gone. Windows Update is the least of your worries.

I have no idea what could have caused such a catastrophic failure.
A serious disk failure is possible, requiring in that case the replacement of the disk,
or maybe some disastrous manipulation you (or somebody) has done.

My best advice is to reformat the hard disk (using slow format) and to reinstall Vista.
As you say that you don't have an installation DVD, I suggest to ask Microsoft Support
for one (assuming that your Windows is legitimate).
Otherwise, search for a suitable torrent and download a copy
(I'm not going to give precise directions on how).

If you wish to ignore my above advice and try to salvage this Vista installation, start
by using chkdsk to repair your hard disk.
See this article :
[The How-To Geek Guide to Using Check Disk in Windows 7 or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/).
Just keep in mind that if the disk is in very bad shape, Windows may no longer boot
after that.

As far as Windows Update goes, I would guess that the access errors you are getting
are on the folders

```
C:\users\default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft
C:\Windows\serviceprofiles\networkservice\appdata\roaming\microsoft
```

Try to give the Full Control permission to the Everyone account on these folders
and try starting slsvc again.

You could also try to create a new administrator account and see whether logon
with it works better.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Now slsvc works, but WinUpdate shows "Unknown error  - C004F012".

Comment: I will ask Microsoft for DVD and reinstall OS

Comment: Did you ever hear about C004F012 error?

Comment: C004F012 = SL_E_VALUE_NOT_FOUND. As I said, repair your Windows by doing an Inplace upgrade.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Did you see what I wrote?

Comment: The error C004F012 normally suggests that Windows is not genuine. You need to reactivate it or [reset the product key](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/ht/changevistakey.htm). You could also try this [Microsoft Fixit](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_update/).

Answer (score 2):

Use your windows Vista Sp2 DVD and [repair Windows by doing an Inplace upgrade](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/88236-repair-install-vista.html).

- Boot into Windows
- Open the Windows DVD and run `setup.exe`
- During setup select "Upgrade":

[image]

Look if this fixes your issues.

Comment: I haven't got install DVD, sorry :-(